# Actualizar informacion de un slider de hijo a padre

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Tengo un componente en el que necesito saber el numero que marca un slider.
En ese componente tengo el slider, con una funcion vacia intento obtener el valor del slider cada vez que este cambia, pero no me funciona, al ponerle la funcion de actualizacion el slider (la barra) no se mueve.

FUNCION EN COMPONENTE PADRE PARA RECIBIR:

```
let [env, updateEnv] = useState(true);
    //cantidad que recibe del hijo, slider
    const actualizar = (v) => {
        updateEnv(v)
        console.log(v)
      }

    //   console.log(env)
```

esta funcion se la paso por parametros al hijo

RangeMk
productsid={productsid}
actualizar={actualizar}

FUNCION HIJO (COMPONENTE RANGEMK) PARA ACTUALIZAR:

```
  const handlerUpdate = (v) => {
    actualizar(v)   
  }
```

En el html tengo lo siguiente, para que se actualice con el onchange

FUNCION HIJO PARA QUE ENVIE Y CAMBIE EL NUMERO DEL SLIDER

```
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(0);
  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setSlider(event.target.value);
    //  console.log(slider);
    handlerUpdate(slider)
  }
      
 <input type="range" min={0} max={prStock} value={slider} className="slider" step={0.01}  onChange={handleOnChange} />
```

Si no le pongo parte de handlerupdate(slider) me funciona, tambien he probado con handlerupdate(event.target.value) pero tampoco me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Para que el componente `RangeMk` envíe el valor del slider cada vez que cambia, debes llamar a la función `handlerUpdate` dentro del `onChange` del `input` del slider, pero antes debes actualizar el estado del componente RangeMk con el nuevo valor del slider. Esto se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
const RangeMk = ({ actualizar }) => {
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(0);

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setSlider(newValue);
    actualizar(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <input type="range" min={0} max={prStock} value={slider} className="slider" step={0.01} onChange={handleOnChange} />
  )
}
```

En este ejemplo se está utilizando la función `useState` de React para manejar el estado del componente. Cuando se cambia el valor del `input`, se actualiza el estado del componente con el nuevo valor y se llama a la función `actualizar` pasándole el nuevo valor como parámetro.